# Ubuntu 22.04 on-screen keyboard stops registering keystrokes (X-org)

Tags: xorg, 22.04, onscreen-keyboard

On a fresh Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS install running on X-org on a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 (it's a convertible laptop with touch screen) I'm using the built-in on-screen keyboard for a full-screen Firefox web application.

The keyboard is always correctly showing up when activating an input in the web application, but after the laptop screen was blank and it woke up again, the keyboard is often not registering key strokes anymore (but not always). When I restart the laptop, it's working perfectly again until after the next "waking up" (the laptop never goes on suspend, only blanks the screen). Interestingly, an external USB keyboard's strokes were also not registered anymore when the on-screen keyboard wasn't working.

One way to get key strokes working again is to open the app overview, tap on the "Type to search" input on the top, tap on a letter on the opened on-screen keyboard (for this input, the on-screen keyboard **always** works), and then go back to Firefox. Then the key strokes are working there again as well.

Does anyone have an idea where this inconsistent buggy behavior may come from?

I tried with default Firefox snap installation, with Chrome .deb install (same behavior), and the Ubuntu is 22.04.1 LTS with GNOME 42.4 and running on X-org.

EDIT
When setting the session to Wayland, the on-screen keyboard doesn't show up at all for inputs in snap Firefox or .deb Chrome but it does for inputs in system apps like in settings. Could there be a connection to the issue described above?